# How to bypass invalid utf8 character string in mysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a large text file containing Arabic text data. When I try to load it into a MySQL table, I get error saying `Error code 1300: invalid utf8 character string`. This is what I have tried so far:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/text_file.txt'
IGNORE INTO TABLE tblTest
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I tried to ignore this error, but it does not work. I have tried `LOCAL INFILE` but it did not work, too. My database was created using `DEFAULT CHAR SET UTF8` and `DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci`. The text file is `utf-8` encoded.

I do not want the records which contain invalid utf8 characters. So how I can load the data with ignoring the records containing such invalid chars?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to have the HEX of the naughty character.

A possible approach to reading all the text, then dealing with any bad characters:

1. Read into a column of type `VARBINARY` or `BLOB`.
2. Loop through the rows, trying to copy to a `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` column.

Another plan is to use utf8mb4 instead of utf8.  It could be that the bad character is an Emoji or Chinese character that will work in utf8mb4, but not utf8.

**Ignore errors**

This *may* let you ignore errors:

```
SET @save := @@sql_mode;
LOAD DATA ...;
SET @@sql_mode := @save;
```

Comment: In Python, I catch any exception and decide the action to do when such exception occurs, e.g. `except ValueError: continue` and so on. But I am not sure if this technique is available in MySQL.

Comment: `Update:` I had to check all the characters that are available in the text file using Python `chars = {c for c in textfile}`. I found a few more strange chars which have been cleaned using `regex`. After that, the `MySQL load statement` worked fine with `utf-8` and `text` as types of text columns. Thanks are extended to `Rick James` for your kind help. I am marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: @RickJames. You have an enormous about of respect from me but your answer is unhelpful. The question isn't about bad characters. It's about ignoring bad characters on import.

Comment: @AuntJemima - Point made.  I added to my answer.  In reviewing `sql_mode`, I wonder if he is hitting a bad date or something unrelated to Arabic.

Comment: @RickJames. Thank you. It doesn't work, but thanks. MySQL 5.7 doesn't have an sql_mode that skips bad characters and the special term `IGNORE` still throws an error instead of a warning, which doesn't do any good either. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html. Is this the same in future releases of MySQL?

Comment: @AuntJemima - I am _guessing_ that `strict_mode` (or maybe something else) would be the difference between "ignore" and "error".  `sql_mode` tends to be augmented in new versions, especially 8.0.  And the default value tends to change -- leading to incompatibilities.  Beware.

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem when try use MySQL 5.7.14, too.

I returned to MySQL 5.6 and this problem is disappeared

Comment: Can you provide the specifics?

Comment: What is the value of `sql_mode`?